# Is sql with more where condition faster than those with less in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-optimization

I hava big table need to be queried by a datetime column every 5 minutes.

My solution is like this:

```
select * from tbl_name where datetime_col < '2019-05-26 20:49:00' and tag_col = 0;
```

,and do something with the result set,and if the "something" succeeds,then update the row and set the tag_col to 1.

One of my colleague has a solution like this:

```
select * from tbl_name where datetime_col < '2019-05-26 20:49:00' and datetime_col >= '2019-05-26 20:44:00' and tag_col = 0;
```

,and do something with the result set,and if the "something" fails,update the row and add 5 minutes to the datetime_col(so that it will be selected next time),and if the "something" succeeds,also update the row and set the tag_col to 1.

My question is whose sql is faster (or they are equally fast) when there is index on the datetime_col?
Thanks.

Comment: Isn’t the important question how much time you save when sending and managing much less data compared to the sql performance?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson yes,you are right.I could use a limit 1000 or something.But before that I need to find the best sql.

Answer (score 1):

If you execute this query:

```
select *
from tbl_name
where datetime_col < '2019-05-26 20:49:00'
```

You are presumably going to be returns lots and lots of data, because -- by your description -- you have a "big table".  You then have to forage through this to get the results you want.

If you execute:

```
select *
from tbl_name
where datetime_col < '2019-05-26 20:49:00'
order by datetime_col desc;
```

Then I think MySQL will use the index and be able to return the rows that you want. However, you are still returning lots and lots of rows. You should test if the performance is okay.

Your colleague's query is:

```
select *
from tbl_name
where datetime_col < '2019-05-26 20:49:00' and
      datetime_col >= '2019-05-26 20:44:00';'
```

This returns only the rows you want -- presumably a much smaller set.  It should use the index to find those rows.

I would expect that your colleague is correct.  Even if the rows don't exist and you have to issue another query, that is probably faster than returning almost the entire table.

Comment: His sql should returns as many rows as mine,or the logic will be wrong. I updated the question added more logic background: there is also a tag_col,if the "something" we do on the result set is successful,then we need to update the tag_col.So my sql won't return the rows that already successfully "do something",but only those haven't "do something" and those failed to "do something".His sql do the same as mine,so his sql returns as many rows as mine.

Comment: And can you explain why select * from tbl_name where datetime_col < '2019-05-26 20:49:00' won't uses the index?

Comment: @冯克勤 . . . Your queries should return different result sets, because yours will return data older than 5 minutes and your colleague's won't.  If you are returning most of the data in the table, it doesn't matter if an index is used or not.

Comment: @Grodon Linoff True, colleague's sql won't retrun rows older than 5 minutes , but if "do something" fails he will update the row and add 5 minutes to the datetime_col, so actually he's sql will retrun rows that older than 5 minutes

Comment: @冯克勤 . . . Your colleague's version is taking data in 5-minute chunks.  That should be much more efficient than taking all the data, even if it requires multiple queries.

Comment: Thanks for replying.Is there any thing to support your theory?Because the execution plans of these two sqls are the same,so I think they should be equally fast in practice.

Comment: @冯克勤 . . .  You are not accounting for the amount of data that you have to process without the lower bound.

Comment: When there is no lower bound,the data should be the rows that is new rows in this 5 minures that haven't "do something",and those rows that failed to "do something" in all past 5 minutes.